# Oracle - Join with comma separated data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.

```
1.Table A                       2.Table B

  **A.Class**                   **B.ID**
  P,H,P0101                      P0101
  p                              P
  H
  P0101
```

And i need the result as

```
   B.ID             A.Class
   P0101            P,H,P0101
   P0101            P0101
   P                P,H,P0101
   P                P
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) Please explain the logic.  It is not obvious.  (2) Fix your data model so you are not storing multiple values in a string column.

Comment: I want to join 2 tables. But I have no idea for solve it .Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap both the `class` you are matching against and the string containing the `id` you want to match in the `,` delimiter so that you ensure you match a complete `id` and then join when the substring matches:

```sql
SELECT b.id, a.class
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN B
       ON ( ','||a.class||',' LIKE '%,'||b.id||',%' )
```

Which, for you sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a ( class ) AS
SELECT 'P,H,P0101' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'P' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'P0101' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE B ( id ) AS
SELECT 'P0101' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'P' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | CLASS |
> | --- | --- |
> | P0101 | P,H,P0101 |
> | P0101 | P0101 |
> | P | P,H,P0101 |
> | P | P |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=437416490e3f83ecce42e72391dbf44e)*